# Advanced stacked labeling in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, labeling

I have problem with building advanced stacked labels in ESRI arcMap 10.2. The example is below. As You can see on the beginning there is a letter which is in the middle of two line after it.

How to do it in one label class?

I am able to build this kind of label but I need two classes for that:

- first with offset showing only first letter
- second with underlined nominator part and denominator line.

Problem is when I change it to annotation in map every label is build from two parts (each for class) and if further movement of anno is necessary its problematic - You need to remember to select two labels, sometimes they overlap extensively and selection is almost impossible.

[image: example labels]

Comment: Make it from 3 lines 3jw45;y---------;0,29

Comment: Are you labelling based on one field, two fields, three??  Can you provide your current label expression?  Need a bit more info if you want an answer and example.

Comment: Label consist with 3 field, first letter, nominator and denominator, unfortunately I can't use 3 line solution because specification give strict spacing rules to this.

Comment: I figured it out, You should interested in <LIN leading={1} > option in text expression, it controls spacing between lines. Add some spaces before nominator and denominator to make sure overlapping will not occurs, and good to go. Thanks for help! P.S After all I finished up with 3 lines.

Comment: If you have found the solution please post it as an answer and accept it.